# ggplot with mean on y and no intermediate data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Need help with ggplot that plots averages for y axis and returns the line plot with points and also the text labels for each points (using ggplot functionality) that are color coded as per the respective "color" object parameter. As far as possible I don't want to create any intermediate dataframe from original data to create summary for y means. I tried using fun.y as shown in the code snippet. Excel chart is also attached.

Sample data

```
set.seed(1)
age_range = sample(c("ar2-15", "ar16-29", "ar30-44"), 20, replace = TRUE)
gender = sample(c("M", "F"), 20, replace = TRUE)
region = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 20, replace = TRUE)
physi = sample(c("Poor", "Average", "Good"), 20, replace = TRUE)
height = sample(c(4,5,6), 20, replace = TRUE)
survey = data.frame(age_range, gender, region,physi,height)
```

ggplot code I tried

```
ggplot(survey, aes(x=age_range, y=height, color=gender)) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "point")+geom_line()
```

Output I am getting

[image]

Output I am looking for

[image]

Comment: Try `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "line")` in place of `geom_line()`

Comment: Thanks Sandy...It generates an error message "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Comment: Sorry, Yes. `group = gender` in aesthetics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on @Sandy's comment, you can also add the labels in a similar fashion, though here I am using the package `ggrepel` to make sure they don't overlap (without having to manually code the location). For the location, you can read the result from the call to `mean` which is returned as `y` by calling `..y..` in the aesthetics.

```
ggplot(survey, aes(x=age_range, y=height, color=gender, group = gender)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "line") +
  stat_summary(aes(label = round(..y.., 2)), fun.y=mean, geom = "label_repel", segment.size = 0)
```

Gives

[image]

(Note that `segment.size = 0` is to ensure that there is not an additional line drawn from the point to the label.)

As of now, it does not appear that `ggrepel` offers text displacement in only one axis (see [here](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/25) ), so you may have to manually position labels if you want more precision.

If you want to set the label locations manually, here is an approach that uses `dplyr` and the `%>%` pipe to avoid having to save any intermediate `data.frame`s

The basic idea is described here. To see the result after any step, just highlight up to just before the `%>%` at the end of a line and run. First, `group_by` the `x` location and grouping that you want to plot. Get the average of each using `summarise`. The data are still `group_by`'d the `age_range` (`summarise` only rolls up one group at a time). So, you can determine which of the groups has a higher mean at that point by subtracting the mean. I used sign just to pull if it was positive or negative, then multiplied/divided by a facto to get the spacing I wanted (in this case, divided by ten to get spacing of 0.1). Add that adjustment to the mean to set where you want the label to land. Then, pass all of that into `ggplot` and proceed as you would with any other `data.frame`.

```
survey %>%
  group_by(age_range, gender) %>%
  summarise(height = mean(height)) %>%
  mutate(myAdj = sign(height - mean(height)) / 10
         , labelLoc = height + myAdj) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age_range
             , y = height
             , label = round(height, 2)
             , color = gender
             , group = gender
  )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(aes(y = labelLoc)
             , show.legend = FALSE)
```

Gives:

[image]

Which seems to accomplish your base goals, though you may want to play around with spacing etc. for your actual use case.

Comment: Thanks Mark...this worked beautifully! Both the options are nicely described and I accept this as an answer. For the first option, one of my laptops gave an error - "error in as.vector(y) : attempt to apply non-function". It worked fine on the other laptop though so I am thinking it has to do with something else. Am researching into it more..Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks again.